# How to DELETE(physical delete) rows from BiTemporal Table

Tags: teradata

I've a bitemporal table where I need to keep current active row and one history row in each month.

IF rows are duplicate within month I need to delete those rows.

```
 Policy_ID  Customer_ID  Validity
```

---

```
  497201    304779902  ('05/06/16', HIGH END)

  540944    304779902  ('07/25/16', '07/30/16')

  541077    304779902  ('07/10/16', '07/24/16')

  541145    304779902  ('07/01/16', '07/10/16')

  541008    304779902  ('06/20/16', '07/01/16')
```

From above row I need to keep 
     Policy_ID  Customer_ID  Validity

---

```
  497201    304779902  ('05/06/16', HIGH END)

  540944    304779902  ('07/25/16', '07/30/16')

  541008    304779902  ('06/20/16', '07/01/16')
```

Any specific command which can help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To actually delete rows you need a NONTEMPORAL delete. The easiest way uses a temp table like this:

```
create volatile table src as
 ( select Policy_ID, Customer_ID, Validity
   from tab
   qualify
     row_number() -- find the rows to delete
     over (partition by Customer_ID order by Validity desc) > 2
 ) with data 
primary index (Customer_ID) -- should be the PI of the target table
on commit preserve rows;

nontemporal
delete from tab
where (Policy_ID, Customer_ID, Validity)
in ( select * from src)
```